# How to create a simple document assembly application for Word documents?

Tags: forms, templates, documentation, infopath

I need to create a simple document assembly application to create Word files. We work with multiple templates, some derivated from others. So, instead of having tons of templates I would like to create something that uses a standard template and allowes me to change the header, footer and different other sections in the document based on my needs.
For example: I will choose a template, then a different introductory paragraph, then a secondary paragraph and so on.

I tried a solution in Infopath, but not sure if this is the simplest one. If you have any suggestions please let me know! (and another thing I am new to this, so no programming clue, but learn quickly)

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of C#, another programming environment for Word (which should be easier for non-programmers, though I don't know whether it's powrful enough to do all you want) is called "VBA": see http://www.google.ca/search?q=vba+word+2007

Comment: Thanks Chris, will try this when will find the time :) In the mean time someone suggested this http://www.xpressdox.com/ and seems it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question were programming-related then a tutorial like the following might be relevent: [Word automation using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx).

However, because you have "no programing clue" I don't understand what kind of solution you're looking for (and, "Word automation using C#" is probably not it, because it requires a knowledge of programming).

Comment: Thanks Chris,
I read the article and it is a little over my knowledge, but I will try to start somewhere and see what I can do.

Comment: If that's the kind of thing you want to do, there may (but I don't know what it is) an easier way to drive/automate Word than using C#: instead of C#, perhaps some kind of "scripting language" and/or scripting environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn to a program that already allows for that. [Pathagoras](http://pathagoras.com) offers a monthly subscription to lower the need for a large amount of capital upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Word automation using Office Interop (COM) is not recommened for server side scenarios (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

If you have to create solution for several users, then you will need a toolkit which supports server side installation. You will probably soon realize that free libraries won't meet your needs and will start looking for 3rd party products.

I have experience with one of such [toolkits](http://www.docentric.com) that can solve your document requirements by using subdocuments or by using conditional content. Since you don't have programming experience you can use MS Word for template layout and conditional logic.